# recover corrupted Apple_APFS

Tags: time-machine, apfs, sparsebundle

I have a Time Machine backup stored on a Synology NAS that got corrupted for some reason (probably a power failure).
The folder containing the sparsebundle is mounted on the Mac using smbfs.

I tried to run `fsck_apfs` but it fails with the following message:

```
error: spaceman cib out of order: 13, expected 4
   Space manager is invalid.
** The container /dev/disk5s2 could not be verified completely.
```

Is there a way to recover the space manager?

Comment: How did you create the TM backup on the Synology? The format used is most likely NOT APFS.

Comment: I just can't remember how I created it. But the format is APFS, according to `hdiutil`: `/dev/disk5s2         Apple_APFS`

Comment: If it shows up in hdiutil, how can it be on the Synology NAS?

Comment: I'm mounting it as a remote folder.

Comment: Please add these details including the mount command used to the question with an edit.

Comment: Time Machine creates a disk image segmented into many parts when the backup destination is a network volume. The disk image has an internal file structure of HFS+ or APFS depending on the macOS version creating the backup. Because it's a segmented disk image with no segment being larger than a few hundred megabytes, it can happily be saved onto almost any network volume such as a NAS.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @The_Stewart  But is there a way to recover the sparse bundle image? are there any tools or tricks to get pass the "space manager" error?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428751/cant-get-time-machine-sparsebundle-to-open-in-time-machine?rq=1